# Python Requests long time before answer -> requests freeze/hangs

Tags: python, api, networking, python-requests

I have an API Server which does long processing at requesting `URL`.

It takes ~30mins until it sends the response.
Via `curl`, all is fine, it takes 30mins and I get the data.

In Python, calling `requests.get(URL)` just hangs and does not return after the 30mins .... but in the server logs, I see that there is the response already sent back.

So why is requests hanging and how could I fix this?

Comment: Can you upload pieace of code in server side related to this?

Comment: It is a python FastAPI server with a normal GET request implementation ... the calculation which happens in it takes ~30mins ( a lot of db operations ) and then I just return a string

Comment: ```@router.get("/data", response_model=str)
async def get_data(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):```

Comment: It can be the problem with ip version 
Verify by executing curl --ipv6 -v https://www.example.com. Then, compare to curl --ipv4 -v https://www.example.com

Comment: I think you have to use ```await``` on what ever you are returning

Comment: no, there is nothing what I need to `await` for. why should I await? I do not perform sync functions. It works and returns the data, there is just the problem that `requests.get` hangs @MOHAMMADWASEEM

Comment: @SuryaveerSingh ill let you know in an hour :D

Comment: @Prutheus the piece of code you have mentioned the function is defined as ```async``` I highly doubt there might be a place where concurrency happens. It would be easy if you can share function body of the function definition.

Comment: @MOHAMMADWASEEM no this makes no sense as the request works from browser and via curl. There is all fine with the function body. There is an issue at requesting via `requests` to that API endpoint. There is no error on server. The server returns the response (after 30mins) but the `requests`-Request just is not getting returned then